# Vaadin TreeTable flickers

Tags: scroll, vaadin, flicker, treetable

The Vaadin TreeTable example at http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!tables (select hierarchical) flickers if nodes are collapsed or expanded. To see it scroll the table a little bit and then expand an item. The items are jumping up and down. If you have more items expanded the jumping is enlarged.

Has anybody an idee what to do to avoid this behaviour? If tried to select node if expanded or to focus tree but this did not help.

Comment: It doesn't flicker on my browser. It just jumps to the selected row when you expand or collapse another row. And the components seem to be loaded lazily so you need to wait a bit for the data to load if you scroll too fast.

Comment: What webbrowser did you use? IE is known to be... not realy a browser

Comment: I use the current FF. I scroll and wait until the data is loaded. Then I expand a node and the table is scrolled a little bit up and than a little bit down.

Comment: It happens to me on FF and Chrome too.

Comment: Nobody has a workround for this problem?